# AWS Schedule AutoScaling via terraform (timezone issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-auto-scaling

I have a common TF code for different regions in my AWS, and similarly have a common autoscaling block in TF for all my regions.

Now I want to do time-based scheduling for my ASG, but since the timezones are different in different regions. I am not able to do the same with TF, because I do not see any option to specify timezone in aws_autoscaling_schedule resource of TF.

Following is my code :

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "schedule1" {
  scheduled_action_name  = "scale_down"
  min_size               = var.min_size
  max_size               = var.max_size
  recurrence             = "0 18 * * 5"
  desired_capacity       = var.min_size
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.example_asg.name
}
```

Now If you see the recurrence, I want to do scale down at 6pm as per respective region timings, but I am not able to achieve the same because the default timezone is UTC.

PS: I have different vars file for every region. And getting max_size and min_size, separately for every region.

I tried manipulating the recurrence block by passing one var in every regions's var file. But doesn't seem to work getting error as we can not pass vars in recurrence block :

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "schedule1" {
  scheduled_action_name  = "scale_down"
  min_size               = var.min_size
  max_size               = var.max_size
  recurrence             = "0 var.temp_var * * 5"
  desired_capacity       = var.min_size
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.example_asg.name
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve the same. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "getting error"  - what error exactly?

Comment: @Marcin, Here is the exact error :  Error: Error Creating Autoscaling Scheduled Action: ValidationError: Given recurrence string: 0 var.max_size * * 5 is invalid
   status code: 400, request id: ************

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome your error and to correctly  pass `var.temp_var` into `recurrence` you should do:

```
recurrence             = "0 ${var.temp_var} * * 5"
```

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 No problem. Glad it worked out.